# How to split an array into arrays by an objects property using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I currently have an array that resembles the array below:

```
[
      {id:1,color:'red'},
      {id:2,color:'blue'},
      {id:3,color:'red'},
      {id:4,color:'green'},
      {id:5,color:'blue'},
]
```

I am looking for the fastest way to get something like below where I could split/sort the array by a property in the object, in this example it would be 'color' :

```
[
      [
        {id:1,color:'red'},
        {id:3,color:'red'},
      ],[
        {id:2,color:'blue'},
        {id:5,color:'blue'},
      ],[
        {id:4,color:'green'},
    ]
]
```

I could write a function for this but I was thinking there may be something to do this already in underscore.js, but had no luck finding it.

Comment: there is a `groupBy` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `groupBy` function of underscore you can find it in the docs right [here](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy).

> **groupBy_.groupBy(list, iterator, [context])**
>   Splits a collection into
>   sets, grouped by the result of running each value through iterator. If
>   iterator is a string instead of a function, groups by the property
>   named by iterator on each of the values.

```
[
      {id:1,color:'red'},
      {id:2,color:'blue'},
      {id:3,color:'red'},
      {id:4,color:'green'},
      {id:5,color:'blue'},
]

_.groupBy(a, function(x){ return x.color; });
```

Comment: That doesn't produce the requested output. Though, the OP may be fine dealing with it as is.

Comment: canon is correct, it returns an object but this should work just as well. Thanks.

Comment: The result of this needs to be wrapped in `_.toArray()` to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `_.groupBy` with the `_.toArray` function:

```
var dict = [
      {id:1,color:'red'},
      {id:2,color:'blue'},
      {id:3,color:'red'},
      {id:4,color:'green'},
      {id:5,color:'blue'},
];

var grouped = _.groupBy(dict, function(x){ return x.color; });
var result = _.toArray(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required results using ES5 features without need of third party libraries:

```
var data = [
      {id:1,color:'red'},
      {id:2,color:'blue'},
      {id:3,color:'red'},
      {id:4,color:'green'},
      {id:5,color:'blue'},
];

var temp = {};
data.forEach(function(item){
    if (temp[item.color]) { 
         temp[item.color].push(item);
     } else {
       temp[item.color] = [ item ]; }   
});

var result = Object.keys(temp).map(function(key){ return temp[key]; });
```

In order to support older browsers use [ES5 shims](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim)